# Flash Builder 4.6 Project issues when transferring from PC to Mac

Tags: macos, air, flash-builder

I have a project that works fine on the PC. I use NativeProcesses which means that I have to build for PC and mac on those respective environments to make a native build.  Here are the details.

Background:
I use Flash Builder 4.6 on both environments.  I'm using AIR SDK 3.5 which I had to manually upgrade in both environments by installing the AIR SDK separately by overlaying the AIDSDK contents in the Flash Builder install environment.  I've tested this on the Mac and I can generate test AIR applications using AIR 3.5.

Here's the problem:
When I transferred my project over it gave me errors for things like

```
<mx:Button>
```

I did some research out found out that I need mx.swc.  In the Mac it appears that it is not in my build path automatically like it is on the PC.  So I added it.  The  errors go away but now I have these other strange errors with respect to my Spark libraries.  For example I have issues using

```
<s:State>
<s:Spacer>
```

in my project. It says it "Could not Resolve". On a PC this is working ok but on the Mac it is giving me these problems.

Not sure how to resolve this. It appears that including the mx.swc solved one problem but caused another.

Any ideas?

Comment: As you did with the `mx.swc`, library did you try tracking down the `spark.swc`?

Comment: The spark.swc was already included in the libs area for this project so I didn't have to bring it in.  If I change the <s:State> to <mx:State> after bringing in the mx.swc the error goes away.  My confusion is why do I have to do that?  The only difference is that I'm moving from the PC to a Mac.  This would mean that I would have to diverge my code for Mac.  Also I'm not sure if in the end it will work.